# Python OOP , TypeError self in my code

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

```
class circle_color:
    def __init__(self):
        self.circle_red = canvas.create_oval(10, 160, 140, 290, fill="red")
        self.circle_blue = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 140, 140, fill="blue")

    def circle_blue_add(self):
            return self.circle_blue

    def circle_red_add(self):
            return self.circle_red

but_circle_blue_add = Button(panel_with_button, text="Add Blue Circle", width=20, command=circle_color.circle_blue_add)
but_circle_blue_add.place(x=10, y=10)

but_circle_blue_del = Button(panel_with_button, text="Add Red Circle", width=20, command=circle_color.circle_blue_add)
but_circle_blue_del.place(x=10, y=50)'
```

**This Error**

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Fleshka\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
    TypeError: circle_blue_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I need to draw two figure one blue and red with oop programming. But I do not understand why it doesn't work

Comment: It's object-oriented, and you don't have an object there.

Comment: To clarify, the `circle_blue_add` method is expecting that you pass it `self` (an instance of the class), and you didn't. Please expand your code sample into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can determine the changes that would be most appropriate for your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to call a *class* method (which I'm guessing is not what you actually want to do). You need to make an *instance* of the class, and call the instance's methods.

```
cc = circle_color()
but_circle_blue_add = Button(panel_with_button, text="Add Blue Circle", width=20, command=cc.circle_blue_add)
```

Comment: Thank you it work ,but when I was running my program already figure on the screen instead of pressing the button

Comment: Yes, `__init__` is a "magic" method that gets called when you instantiate a class, i.e. upon `circle_color()`.